# Can't build Jack-Rack: GTK "has no member named ‘midi_menu_item’, ‘midi_menu’"

Tags: c, makefile, gtk, jack

I am trying to build [Jack Rack](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jack-rack/) on Solus Linux, but I get an error when I try to build it using `make` command (the error is shown below) (I did run `./configure` first)

I suppose the problem is that the GTK API has changed, but I've never even touched the GTK-related C code.

Is there any way to fix it without changing the code? If not, what do I need to change in the code?

```
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from plugin_slot_callbacks.c:30:
plugin_slot_callbacks.c: In function ‘slot_ablise_cb’:
plugin_slot_callbacks.c:112:48: error: ‘ui_t’ {aka ‘struct _ui’} has no member named ‘midi_menu_item’; did you mean ‘add_menuitem’?
  112 |               g_object_set_data (G_OBJECT (ui->midi_menu_item),
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2417:57: note: in definition of macro ‘_G_TYPE_CIC’
 2417 |     ((ct*) g_type_check_instance_cast ((GTypeInstance*) ip, gt))
      |                                                         ^~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:52:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST’
   52 | #define G_OBJECT(object)            (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST ((object), G_TYPE_OBJECT, GObject))
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
plugin_slot_callbacks.c:112:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_OBJECT’
  112 |               g_object_set_data (G_OBJECT (ui->midi_menu_item),
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~
plugin_slot_callbacks.c:115:48: error: ‘ui_t’ {aka ‘struct _ui’} has no member named ‘midi_menu_item’; did you mean ‘add_menuitem’?
  115 |               g_object_set_data (G_OBJECT (ui->midi_menu_item),
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2417:57: note: in definition of macro ‘_G_TYPE_CIC’
 2417 |     ((ct*) g_type_check_instance_cast ((GTypeInstance*) ip, gt))
      |                                                         ^~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:52:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST’
   52 | #define G_OBJECT(object)            (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST ((object), G_TYPE_OBJECT, GObject))
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
plugin_slot_callbacks.c:115:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_OBJECT’
  115 |               g_object_set_data (G_OBJECT (ui->midi_menu_item),
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~
plugin_slot_callbacks.c:118:45: error: ‘ui_t’ {aka ‘struct _ui’} has no member named ‘midi_menu’; did you mean ‘add_menu’?
  118 |               gtk_menu_popup (GTK_MENU (ui->midi_menu), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, event->button, event->time);
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2417:57: note: in definition of macro ‘_G_TYPE_CIC’
 2417 |     ((ct*) g_type_check_instance_cast ((GTypeInstance*) ip, gt))
      |                                                         ^~
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkmenu.h:42:42: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST’
   42 | #define GTK_MENU(obj)                   (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST ((obj), GTK_TYPE_MENU, GtkMenu))
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
plugin_slot_callbacks.c:118:31: note: in expansion of macro ‘GTK_MENU’
  118 |               gtk_menu_popup (GTK_MENU (ui->midi_menu), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, event->button, event->time);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [Makefile:638: jack_rack-plugin_slot_callbacks.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What is the specific GTK+ version with which you are trying to build?

Comment: @BobMorane, I have gtk2 and gtk3 installed, it looks like the makefile uses gtk2 by the looks of the output